# How do the Proxy, Decorator, Adapter, and Bridge Patterns differ?

Tags: design-patterns, decorator, bridge, proxy-pattern

I was looking at the Proxy Pattern, and to me it seems an awful lot like the Decorator, Adapter, and Bridge patterns. Am I misunderstanding something? What's the difference? Why would I use the Proxy pattern versus the others? How have you used them in the past in real world projects?

Comment: There are often patterns that look very similar, but differ in their intent (the strategy and state patterns come to mind). I think this is often due to the fact that design patterns are based on common solid design principles.

Comment: Well, these four patterns have the exact same implementation details.  State verses Strategy can at least be summed up as state-full verses stateless (for the most part).  Often, the Strategy is just method injection, where the state pattern uses an interface to do more then abstract away a method call. The strategy, also, at the end of the day, is a hack to allow functional programming in the OO world.

Answer (score 739, accepted):

Proxy, Decorator, Adapter, and Bridge are all variations on "wrapping" a class.  But their uses are different.

- **Proxy** could be used when you want to lazy-instantiate an object, or hide the fact that you're calling a remote service, or control access to the object.
- **Decorator** is also called "Smart Proxy."  This is used when you want to add functionality to an object, but not by extending that object's type.  This allows you to do so at runtime.
- **Adapter** is used when you have an abstract interface, and you want to map that interface to another object which has similar functional role, but a different interface.
- **Bridge** is very similar to Adapter, but we call it Bridge when you define both the abstract interface and the underlying implementation.  I.e. you're not adapting to some legacy or third-party code, you're the designer of all the code but you need to be able to swap out different implementations.
- **Facade** is a higher-level (read: simpler) interface to a subsystem of one or more classes. Suppose you have a complex concept that requires multiple objects to represent. Making changes to that set of objects is confusing, because you don't always know which object has the method you need to call. That's the time to write a Facade that provides high-level methods for all the complex operations you can do to the collection of objects. Example: a Domain Model for a school section, with methods like `countStudents()`, `reportAttendance()`, `assignSubstituteTeacher()`, and so on.

Comment: Good answer. May be worth adding some examples of where you see it in the wild? e.g Proxy classes in Web Services. +1 from me.

Comment: @Rob: thanks, but I'd rather keep this answer short and sweet.  I encourage you to write another answer with examples in the wild!

Comment: @BillKarwin The best way to add functionality to an object is to extend its type, at least in C++. So your definition of Decorator isn't quite clear to me. What do mean?

Comment: @RobertDailey, you can't extend a C++ class without writing new code and compiling it.  But a Decorator class can apply supplementary functions to a C++ class at runtime.

Comment: @RobertDailey Decorator is also good to avoid out of control type hierarchies. [For example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern#First_Example_.28window.2Fscrolling_scenario.29), say you have a window in a GUI and you want to have optional scroll bars. You could have Window, VScrollWindow, HScrollWindow, and VHScrollWindow classes or you could make VScroll and HScroll decorators on Window.

Comment: @Eva, yes, good point!  Type hierarchies have to be trees.  With Decorators, we can add functionality in a more flexible way.

Comment: @BillKarwin Same for Decorator... it requires new code, but just uses composition instead of inheritance. You can't add code at runtime (not in C++), the code has to be written, and recompiled.

Comment: @Eva Looking back on my comment from a year ago I'm not really sure what I was trying to say (lol) but I wouldn't advocate inheritance for everything. There has to be a strong is-a relationship for it to make sense, otherwise I tend to prefer composition/aggregation.

Comment: @RobertDailey, Decorator *is* composition.

Comment: @BillKarwin I know that, you're not really making a point. Did I need to say Decorator explicitly in order for people to understand my statement?

Comment: What about a wrapper that exposes a subset of the methods of the wrapped object, without adding additional logic or filters? Would that be a decorator? Or a Proxy? Or an Adpater? See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/247325/object-pointer-with-privileged-access/247329#247329

Comment: And what if you want to duplicate the interface of the wrapped object 1:1 but then add a few additional methods? Is this a decorator or an adapter?

Comment: @donquixote, I would consider that a Decorator, since the interface is a superset of the base class.

Comment: can you provide some sample for them? in semi-simple application

Comment: @deadManN, no, I'm not going to do that.

Comment: @BillKarwin, this is an excellent and concise answer! I think it leaves the intent of the Facade pattern unclear, though. Could you clarify that last item a bit?

Comment: @BillKarwin, thanks. I think I do understand Facade (at least as our team has used it), but could you consider updating your answer above? That's the one part I don't think is as clear/helpful yet.

Comment: Where is Decorator called "_Smart Proxy_"? I don't believe that phrase occurs in the GoF book.

Comment: @jaco0646 For example: https://wiki.c2.com/?ProxyPattern "There are also a proxy type called 'Smart Proxy'. This could provide additional functionality over that offered by the existing object.
[This is DecoratorPattern.]"

Comment: Is the injection of EntityManager in Spring an example of proxy pattern? (as there is not a real EM, but one EM per thread)

Comment: @Ekaterina, Sorry, I don't know Spring or EntityManager. I'll have to leave that for someone else to answer.

Answer (score 235):

[As Bill's answer says, their use cases are different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350404/how-do-the-proxy-decorator-adaptor-and-bridge-patterns-differ/350471#350471).

So are their structures.

- **Proxy** and **Decorator** both have the same interface as their wrapped types, but the proxy creates an instance under the hood, whereas the decorator takes an instance in the constructor.
- **Adapter** and **Facade** both have a different interface than what they wrap. But the adapter derives from an existing interface, whereas the facade creates a new interface.
- **Bridge** and **Adapter** both point at an existing type. But the bridge will point at an abstract type, and the adapter might point to a concrete type.  The bridge will allow you to pair the implementation at runtime, whereas the adapter usually won't.

Comment: Your answer combined with Bill's wraps up 5 chapters of Design Patterns very nicely. One could call them a higher-level (read: simpler) interface to the book.

Comment: I would say that the `Adapter` usually depends on one interface (needed to be adapted to another - like what you say about deriving), but it may still create (introduce) a new interface (adapted from the dependency interface). The difference between `Adapter` and `Facade` is about the number of dependencies, `Facade` usually consumes a lot of miscellaneous interfaces (not just usually one like `Adapter`) and combines them to spit out a common interface which serves some purpose.

Answer (score 67):

My take on the subject.

All four patterns have a lot in common, all four are sometimes informally called wrappers, or wrapper patterns. All use composition, wrapping subject and delegating the execution to the subject at some point, do mapping one method call to another one. They spare client the necessity of having to construct a different object and copy over all relevant data. If used wisely, they save memory and processor.

By promoting loose coupling they make once stable code less exposed to inevitable changes and better readable for fellow developers.

**Adapter**

Adapter adapts subject (adaptee) to a different interface. This way we can add object be placed to a collection of nominally different types.

Adapter expose only relevant methods to client, can restrict all others, revealing usage intents for particular contexts, like adapting external library, make it appear less general and more focused on our application needs. Adapters increase readability and self description of our code.

Adapters shields one team from volatile code from other teams; a life savior tool when dealing with offshore teams ;-)

Less mentioned purpose it to prevent the subject class from excess of annotations. With so many frameworks based on annotations this becomes more important usage then ever.

Adapter helps to get around Java limitation of only single inheritance. It can combine several adaptees under one envelope giving impression of multiple inheritance.

Code wise, Adapter is “thin”. It should not add much code to the adaptee class, besides simply calling the adaptee method and occasional data conversions necessary to make such calls.

There are not many good adapter examples in JDK or basic libraries. Application developers create Adapters, to adapt libraries to application specific interfaces.

**Decorator**

Decorator not only delegate, not only maps one method to another, they do more, they modify behaviour of some subject methods, it can decide not call subject method at all, delegate to a different object, a helper object.

Decorators typically add (transparently) functionality to wrapped object like logging, encryption, formatting, or compression to subject. This New functionality may bring a lot of new code. Hence, decorators are usually much “fatter” then Adapters.

Decorator must be a sub-class of subject's interface. They can be used transparently instead of its subjects. See BufferedOutputStream, it is still OutputStream and can be used as such. That is a major technical difference from Adapters.

Text book examples of whole decorators family is readily in JDK - the Java IO. All classes like [BufferedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html), [FilterOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html) and [ObjectOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) are decorators of [OutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html). They can be onion layered, where one one decorator is decorated again, adding more functionality.

**Proxy**

Proxy is not a typical wrapper. The wrapped object, the proxy subject, may not yet exist at the time of proxy creation. Proxy often creates it internally. It may be a heavy object created on demand, or it is remote object in different JVM or different network node and even a non-Java object, a component in native code. It does not have to necessary wrap or delegate to another object at all.

Most typical examples are remote proxies, heavy object initializers and access proxies.

- Remote Proxy – subject is on remote server, different JVM or even non
  Java system. Proxy translates method calls to RMI/REST/SOAP calls or
  whatever is needed, shielding client from exposure to underlying
  technology.
- Lazy Load Proxy – fully initialize object only the first usage or
  first intensive usage.
- Access Proxy – control access to subject.

**Facade**

Facade is closely associated with design Principle of Least Knowledge (Law of Demeter).
Facade is very similar to Adapter. They both wrap, they both map one object to another, but they differ in the intent. Facade flattens complex structure of a subject, complex object graph, simplifying access to a complex structure.

Facade wraps a complex structure, providing a flat interface to it. This prevents client object from being exposed to inner relations in subject structure hence promoting loose coupling.

**Bridge**

More complex variant of Adapter pattern where not only implementation varies but also abstraction. It adds one more indirection to the delegation. The extra delegation is the bridge. It decouples Adapter even from adapting interface. It increases complexity more than any other of the other wrapping patterns, so apply with care.

**Differences in constructors**

Pattern differences are also obvious when looking at their constructors.

- **Proxy** is not wrapping an existing object. There is no subject in constructor.
- **Decorator** and **Adapter** does wrap already existing object, and such is typically
  provided in the constructor.
- **Facade** constructor takes root element of a whole object graph, otherwise it looks 
  same as Adapter.

Real life example – [JAXB Marshalling Adapter](https://bitbucket.org/espinosa/a-java-playground/src/078ae4a51f4a2f384fd87c727b7becbba3e4fe2f/src/main/java/my/code/a001/adapter/BinaryResourceBatchJaxbAdapter.java?at=master). Purpose of this adapter is mapping of a simple flat class to more complex structure required externally and to prevent "polluting" subject class with excessive annotations.

Answer (score 31):

There's a great deal of overlap in many of the GoF patterns. They're all built on the power of polymorphism and sometimes only really differ in intent. (strategy vs. state)

My understanding of patterns increased 100 fold after reading [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124).

I highly recommend it!

Answer (score 17):

All good answers from experts have already explained what does each pattern stands for.

I will *decorate* key points.

***Decorator:***

1. *Add behaviour to object at run time*. Inheritance is the key to achieve this functionality, which is both advantage and disadvantage of this pattern.
2. It modifies the *behaviour* of interface.

e.g. (with chaining ) : *`java.io` package classes related to `InputStream` & `OutputStream` interfaces*

```
FileOutputStream fos1 = new FileOutputStream("data1.txt");  
ObjectOutputStream out1 = new ObjectOutputStream(fos1);
```

***Proxy:***

1. *Use it for lazy initialization, performance improvement by caching the object and controlling access to the client/caller*. It may provide alternative behaviour or call real object. During this process, it may create new Object.
2. Unlike *Decorator*, which allows chaining of objects, Proxy *does not allow chaining.*

e.g.: `java.rmi` package classes.

***Adapter:***

1. *It allows two unrelated interfaces to work together through the different objects*, possibly playing same role.
2. *It modifies original interface*.

e.g. `java.io.InputStreamReader` (`InputStream` returns a `Reader`)

***Bridge:***

1. *It allows both abstractions and implementations to vary independently*.
2. It uses *composition over inheritance*.

e.g. Collection classes in `java.util`. `List` implemented by `ArrayList`.

**Key notes:**

1. ***Adapter*** provides a different interface to its subject. ***Proxy*** provides the same interface. ***Decorator*** provides an enhanced interface.
2. ***Adapter*** changes an object's interface, ***Decorator*** enhances an object's responsibilities.
3. ***Decorator*** and ***Proxy*** have different purposes but similar structures
4. ***Adapter*** makes things work after they're designed; ***Bridge*** makes them work before they are.
5. ***Bridge*** is designed up-front to let the abstraction and the implementation vary independently. ***Adapter*** is retrofitted to make unrelated classes work together
6. ***Decorator*** is designed to let you add responsibilities to objects without subclassing.

Have a look at great SE questions/articles regarding examples of various design patterns

[When to Use the Decorator Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549743/when-to-use-the-decorator-pattern/37504043#37504043)

[When do you use the Bridge Pattern? How is it different from Adapter pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319728/when-do-you-use-the-bridge-pattern-how-is-it-different-from-adapter-pattern/37514779#37514779)

[Differences between Proxy and Decorator Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618779/differences-between-proxy-and-decorator-pattern/36476818#36476818)

Comment: Sorry did not get what you meant. Regarding decorator you say, 'Inheritance is the key to achieve this functionality, which is both advantage and disadvantage of this pattern'. And at the same time 'Decorator is designed to let you add responsibilities to objects without subclassing'. These two contradict each other in my opinion

Answer (score 8):

They are quite similar, and the lines between them are quite gray. I suggest you read the [Proxy Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ProxyPattern) and [Decorator Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DecoratorPattern) entries in the c2 wiki.

The entries and discussions there are quite extensive, and they also link to other relevant articles. By the way, the c2 wiki is excellent when wondering about the nuances between different patterns.

To sum the c2 entries up, I would say a decorator adds/changes behavior, but a proxy has more to do with access control (lazy instantiation, remote access, security etc). But like I said, the lines between them are gray, and I see references to proxies that could easily be viewed as decorators and vice versa.

Answer (score 6):

This is quote from 
[Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124)

Definitions belongs to book. Examples belongs to me.

**Decorator** - Doesn’t alter the interface, but adds responsibility. Assume you have a car interface,
when you implement this for different model of the car (s, sv, sl) you may need to **add more responsibility** for some models. Like has sunroof, airbag etc..

**Adapter** - Converts one interface to another. You have a car interface and you would like it to act like jeep. So you take the car, modify it and turn into a jeep. **Since it is not a real jeep. But acts like a jeep.**

**Facade** - Makes an interface simpler.  Assume you have car, airplane, ship interfaces. Actually all you need is a class which sends people from one location to another. You want facade to decide what vehicle to use. Then you collect all those **interface references** under 1 umbrella and let it decide/delegate to keep it simple.

Head First: "A facade not only simplifies an interface, it decouples a client from a subsystem 
of components.
Facades and adapters may wrap multiple classes, but a facade’s intent is to simplify, while 
an adapter’s is to convert the interface to something different."

Answer (score 5):

All of the four patterns involve wrapping inner object/class with outer one, so they are very similar structurally. I would outline difference by the purpose:

- **Proxy** encapsulates access in outer to inner.
- **Decorator** modifies or extends behaviour of inner with outer.
- **Adaptor** converts interface from inner to outer.
- **Bridge** separates invariable part of behaviour (outer) from variable or platform-dependent part (inner).

And by interface variation between inner and outer objects:

- in **Proxy** interfaces are the same.
- in **Decorator** interfaces are the same.
- in **Adaptor** interfaces are different formally, but fulfil the same purpose.
- in **Bridge** interfaces are different conceptually.

Answer (score 1):

I use it quite often when consuming web services.  The Proxy Pattern should probably be renamed to something more pragmatic, like 'Wrapper Pattern".  I also have a library that is a Proxy to MS Excel.  It makes it very easy to automate Excel, without having to worry about background details such as what version is installed (if any).

Comment: Wouldn't that just be the Adaptor Pattern?

Comment: A web service is consumed by a Proxy, whereas the Adapter Pattern is used more for the conversion or translation of data from one form to another.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking detail implementation, I find a difference between Proxy and Decorator, Adapter, Facade ... In common implementation of these patterns there's a target object wrapped by a enclosing object. Client uses enclosing object instead of target object. And the target object actually play an important part inside some of methods of enclosing object.

However, in case of Proxy, enclosing object can play some methods by itself, it just initialize target object when client calls some methods that it needs target object take part in. This is lazy initialization. In case of other patterns, enclosing object is virtually based on target object. So target object is always initialized along with enclosing object in constructors/setters.

Another thing, a proxy does exactly what a target does whereas other patterns add more functionality to target.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add examples to Bill Karwing answer (which is great btw.)
I add also some key differences of implementation, that I feel are missing

Quoted parts are from answer of [https://stackoverflow.com/a/350471/1984346] (Bill Karwing)

> Proxy, Decorator, Adapter, and Bridge are all variations on "wrapping" a class.
>   But their uses are different.
>
> - **Proxy** could be used when you want to lazy-instantiate an object, or
>     hide the fact that you're calling a remote service, or control access
>     to the object.

ProxyClass and ObjectClass that is proxied, should implement same interface, so they are interchangable

**Example - proxy expensive object**

```
class ProxyHumanGenome implements GenomeInterface  {
    private $humanGenome = NULL; 

    // humanGenome class is not instantiated at construct time
    function __construct() {
    }

    function getGenomeCount() {
        if (NULL == $this->humanGenome) {
            $this->instantiateGenomeClass(); 
        }
        return $this->humanGenome->getGenomeCount();
    }
} 
class HumanGenome implement GenomeInterface { ... }
```

> - **Decorator** is also called "Smart Proxy." This is used when you want to
>     add functionality to an object, but not by extending that object's
>     type. This allows you to do so at runtime.

DecoratorClass should(could) implement extended interface of ObjectClass. So the ObjectClass could be replaced by DecoratorClass, but not vice versa.

**Example - adding addition functionality**

```
class DecoratorHumanGenome implements CheckGenomeInterface  {

    // ... same code as previous example

    // added functionality
    public function isComplete() {
        $this->humanGenome->getCount >= 21000
    }
}

interface CheckGenomeInterface extends GenomeInterface {

    public function isComplete();

}

class HumanGenome implement GenomeInterface { ... }
```

> - **Adapter** is used when you have an abstract interface, and you want to
>     map that interface to another object which has similar functional
>     role, but a different interface.

**Implentation differences Proxy, Decorator, Adapter**

Adapter provides a different interface to its subject. Proxy provides the same interface. Decorator provides an enhanced interface.

> - **Bridge** is very similar to Adapter, but we call it Bridge when you
>     define both the abstract interface and the underlying implementation.
>     I.e. you're not adapting to some legacy or third-party code, you're
>     the designer of all the code but you need to be able to swap out
>     different implementations.
> - **Facade** is a higher-level (read: simpler) interface to a subsystem of
>     one or more classes. Suppose you have a complex concept that requires
>     multiple objects to represent. Making changes to that set of objects
>     is confusing, because you don't always know which object has the
>     method you need to call. That's the time to write a Facade that
>     provides high-level methods for all the complex operations you can do
>     to the collection of objects. Example: a Domain Model for a school
>     section, with methods like `countStudents()`, `reportAttendance()`,
>     `assignSubstituteTeacher()`, and so on.

Most of the information in this answer is from **https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns**, which I recommend as an **excellent resource** for design patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I believe code will give a clear ideas (to complement others answers as well). Please see below, (Focus the types that a class implements and wraps)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* Proxy */

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine("PROXY");
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

            //instead of creating here create using a factory method, the facory method will return the proxy
            IReal realProxy = new RealProxy();
            Console.WriteLine("calling do work with the proxy object ");
            realProxy.DoWork();

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine("ADAPTER");
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

            /*Adapter*/
            IInHand objectIHave = new InHand();
            Api myApi = new Api();
            //myApi.SomeApi(objectIHave); /*I cant do this, use a adapter then */
            IActual myAdaptedObject = new ActualAdapterForInHand(objectIHave);
            Console.WriteLine("calling api with  my adapted obj");
            myApi.SomeApi(myAdaptedObject);


            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
            Console.WriteLine("DECORATOR");
            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

            /*Decorator*/
            IReady maleReady = new Male();
            Console.WriteLine("now male is going to get ready himself");
            maleReady.GetReady();

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

            IReady femaleReady = new Female();
            Console.WriteLine("now female is going to get ready her self");
            femaleReady.GetReady();

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

            IReady maleReadyByBeautician = new Beautician(maleReady);
            Console.WriteLine("now male is going to get ready by beautician");
            maleReadyByBeautician.GetReady();

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

            IReady femaleReadyByBeautician = new Beautician(femaleReady);
            Console.WriteLine("now female is going to get ready by beautician");
            femaleReadyByBeautician.GetReady();

            Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);

            Console.ReadLine();


        }
    }

    /*Proxy*/

    public interface IReal
    {
        void DoWork();
    }

    public class Real : IReal
    {
        public void DoWork()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("real is doing work ");
        }
    }


    public class RealProxy : IReal
    {
        IReal real = new Real();

        public void DoWork()
        {
            real.DoWork();
        }
    }

    /*Adapter*/

    public interface IActual
    {
        void DoWork();
    }

    public class Api
    {
        public void SomeApi(IActual actual)
        {
            actual.DoWork();
        }
    }

    public interface IInHand
    {
        void DoWorkDifferently();
    }

    public class InHand : IInHand
    {
        public void DoWorkDifferently()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("doing work slightly different ");
        }
    }

    public class ActualAdapterForInHand : IActual
    {
        IInHand hand = null;

        public ActualAdapterForInHand()
        {
            hand = new InHand();
        }

        public ActualAdapterForInHand(IInHand hnd)
        {
            hand = hnd;
        }

        public void DoWork()
        {
            hand.DoWorkDifferently();
        }
    }

    /*Decorator*/

    public interface IReady
    {
        void GetReady();
    }

    public class Male : IReady
    {
        public void GetReady()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Taking bath.. ");
            Console.WriteLine("Dress up....");
        }
    }

    public class Female : IReady
    {
        public void GetReady()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Taking bath.. ");
            Console.WriteLine("Dress up....");
            Console.WriteLine("Make up....");
        }
    }

    //this is a decorator
    public class Beautician : IReady
    {
        IReady ready = null;

        public Beautician(IReady rdy)
        {
            ready = rdy;
        }

        public void GetReady()
        {
            ready.GetReady();
            Console.WriteLine("Style hair ");

            if (ready is Female)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("doing ready process " + i);
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Design pattern is not mathematics, it is combination of art and software engineering. There is nothing like for this requirment you have to use proxy, bridge etc. Design patterns are created to solve the problems. If you anticipate a design problem, then use it. Based on experience, you will come to know for specific problem, which pattern to use. If you are good in solid design principles, you would have implemented design pattern without knowing it is pattern. Common example is statergy and factory patterns

Hence concentrate more on solid desighn principles, clean coding principles and ttd

Comment: Agree, though it's not replying the question.