# How to inherit a C++ class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, embedding, spidermonkey

I am embedding [SpiderMonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpiderMonkey_%28JavaScript_engine%29) to make my C++ library scriptable. To make it extendable, I need it possible to define a new class (JavaScript) inheriting one C++ base class of the library.

Is there an example showing me how to do that using SpiderMonkey?

Comment: have you had a look at this: http://egachine.berlios.de/embedding-sm-best-practice/embedding-sm-best-practice.html#id2510183 ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have read that article before, but I didn't find the solution to my question.

My question is not to map Mapping inheritance of existing C++ classes. In my case, I wish I could sub-class existing C++ class in my Javascript code and use it in my C++ program. 

Many thanks.

Comment: Err... don't do that. One probably should not be inheriting from library classes; instead, make your class usable through composition.

Comment: Yes I was thinking about just providing a C++ scriptable base class which can call Javascript callback functions. Not sure if it's exactly what you meant :) Many thanks. BTW, any example is welcome.

Comment: The concept of inheritance between the two languages is not the same so I am not really sure what you mean...Anyhow, check this http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html

Answer (score 3):

I'd think you cannot subclass a C++ class in SpiderMonkey/JavaScript and use it transparently in the rest of your C++ code. However, you could create a wrapping class in C++ that delegates its work to a couple of JavaScript classes/functions. If you make your C++ class configurable enough that should work for your situation. Both calling JavaScript code from C and C code from JavaScript is explaind in the [JSAPI User Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_C_Engine_Embedder%27s_Guide) page (I think you've already read that one).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know it's possible, but a feeling says you're better off writing a [wrapper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889160/what-is-a-wrapper-class) in JavaScript for the class in the C++ library.