# What is interface and wrapper?

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface, wrapper

I know why use interface and wrapper.

But I confuse to name wrapper class... ("Who is wrapper?" I see I do not know well...)

```
public Interface A {
    void method();
}

public Class B implements A {
    void method() {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

I am confused by two things...

> 1. Wrapper **Class** is class , so B is wrapper.
> 2. We usually see(or think?) a.method() not b.method(), so A is wrapper.

**What is wrapper?**

A? B?

And...

**How to name A,B good using "Wrapper" or "W"?**

A, AWrapper? or B, BWrapper? or others...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A` is an interface.  `B` is a concrete implementation of `Interface`.  Nothing else can be said about them from the code you provided.

A [Wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889160/what-is-a-wrapper-class) "wraps" the functionality of another class or API by adding or simplifying the functionality of the wrapped class/API.  For example, the [Primitive Wrappers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class) from Java add useful methods like `doubleValue` and `compareTo` to Java primitives.

You're thinking of [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).

That's what allows us to say things like:

```
A a = new B();
B b = new B();
List<A> stuffs = new ArrayList<A>();
stuffs.add(b);
```

---

Side note:

`Interface` and `Class` are not allowed to be capitalize in Java.  Your declarations should be like so:

```
public interface A {
  // methods
}

public class B implements A {
  // methods
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know other examples (not Primitive Wrappers)?

Answer (score 3):

Neither A or B from your example can be called a wrapper. The relationship between A and B is `Inheritance`. A `Wrapper` class usually `contains` one or more `Wrappee` objects. Adapter and Facade patterns are good examples of wrappers.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889160/what-is-a-wrapper-class) for a detailed discussion on Wrappers