# What is a wrapper for an instance when using AppDomain.CreateInstance?

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

May be a basic question:

I went through this,

```
secondDomain.CreateInstance("AssemblyA", "AssemblyA.Demo", true,
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, 
    new object[] { 7, 3 }, null, null);
```

And looked at the explanation in form of comments.

```
   // Returns:
    //     An object that is a wrapper for the new instance specified by typeName. The
    //     return value needs to be unwrapped to access the real object.
```

MSDN: [AppDomain.CreateInstance Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/023e4w79%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

What is wrapper for object in this context? Why is this used? How to unwrap this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889160/what-is-a-wrapper-class

Comment: To answer your question on how to unwrap.  You can use the CreateInstanceAndUnwrap method instead for this.

Comment: @defaultlocale: I don't think that's a duplicate. His question is specific about that method. The question you linked is a question about wrapper classes in general. Completely different.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth `What is wrapper for object in C#? Why this is used?` I believe OP can find answers to these questions there. Maybe OP should concentrate on `how to unwrap this` particular object from this particular method part.

Comment: @defaultlocale: You shouldn't always take the questions too literal. He *obviously* is asking his question in the context of `AppDomain.CreateInstance`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see a wrapper as a 'c' or 'c++' pointer to another object.
You can unwrap it using the [Unwrap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle.unwrap.aspx) method:

```
MyType testObj = (MyType) obj.Unwrap();
```

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.runtime.remoting.objecthandle.aspx) for more info.