# Why wasn't Joda Interval made comparable?

Tags: java, jodatime

I've been attempting to generate a `TreeMap<Interval, Set<Object>>` for storing person entities in age-grouped sets where the `Interval` describes the boundary of the age group. I got the following error when I attempted to do this.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.joda.time.Interval cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

Swapping `Interval` for a `DateTime` works perfectly, but the map's key then must be used as input to create an `Interval`.

Why wasn't Joda `Interval` made comparable?

Comment: Because it doesn't `implements Comparable<Interval>`? What's your question here?

Comment: write your own wrapper that implements Comparable

Comment: Yeah, that's the technical reason, but I'm more after "why not", given many of the other classes are comparable.

Comment: No one can answer that except the developers of Joda.

Comment: In regard to the downvotes, I quote @PaulSonier (see [this question from 6 years ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889160/what-is-a-wrapper-class)): "I don't see the harm of having a set of basic questions in the SO archives. SO is for beginners as well as for experts; just because you find something 'stupid' doesn't mean that everyone does."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intervals can be compared in many ways. The javadoc of Interval states it explicitly:

> The duration is represented separately by ReadableDuration. As a result, intervals are not comparable. To compare the length of two intervals, you should compare their durations.
>
> An interval can also be converted to a ReadablePeriod.

For a longer explanation, consider the following intervals and define how they should be ordered:

```
10:00 - 12:00
11:00 - 13:00
11:00 - 12:00
 9:00 - 10:00
 9:00 - 13:00
```

Should they be ordered by duration (timespan)?

```
11:00 - 12:00  (1 hours)
 9:00 - 10:00  (1 hours)
10:00 - 12:00  (2 hours)
11:00 - 13:00  (2 hours)
 9:00 - 13:00  (4 hours)
```

Or by start time?

```
 9:00 - 10:00
 9:00 - 13:00
10:00 - 12:00
11:00 - 13:00
11:00 - 12:00
```

Or by start time, then duration?

```
 9:00 - 10:00  (1 hours)
 9:00 - 13:00  (4 hours)
10:00 - 12:00  (2 hours)
11:00 - 12:00  (1 hours)
11:00 - 13:00  (2 hours)
```

Or by end time, then duration?

```
 9:00 - 10:00  (1 hours)
11:00 - 12:00  (1 hours)
10:00 - 12:00  (2 hours)
11:00 - 13:00  (2 hours)
 9:00 - 13:00  (4 hours)
```

As you can see, there is no single clear definition of "natural ordering", which is what [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) defines:

> This interface imposes a total ordering on the objects of each class that implements it. This ordering is referred to as the class's *natural ordering*, and the class's `compareTo` method is referred to as its *natural comparison method*.

Comment: Pierre, very nice reference to the javadoc. Hope you like my add-on. ;-)

Comment: Thank you, that explains the problem nicely.

Comment: Andreas, OMG you did it all. You should be the owner of that answer! Thank you sir.