# Which packages in Java contain Wrapper Class?

Tags: java, class, package, wrapper

List all the packages in Java which contain the 'Wrapper Class' for example java.lang.
Does java.util contain the Wrapper class?

Comment: @WiktorEriksson any Wrapper class

Comment: U mean Integer, Float, Character, Double, etc classes?

Comment: @WiktorEriksson yes

Comment: Explaining my downvote: this reads like a question on a questionaire, and can be looked up in the jdk javadoc in seconds.

Comment: What exactly is wrapper class? [Here is what I expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889160/what-is-a-wrapper-class). Wrapper is a design pattern!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are in java.lang.

The wrappers is Byte, Short, Integer, Long, Float, Double, Character and Boolean.

```
Integer i = new Integer(26);
int j = i.intValue(); // 26
```

EDIT 1: There are no wrappers in java.util.

EDIT 2: All number wrappers extends Number.

EDIT 3: There are Optional in java.util. In Java 8+, it uses generic Optional.

EDIT 4: Optional is'nt a primitive wrapper

Comment: `There are no wrappers in java.util.` what about `Optional` or `Date`?

Comment: Yeah, Optional<T> is, but Date?

Comment: @Piro So you mean `Optional` and `Date` are wrapper classes?

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I edited and `Optional<T>` is but not `Date`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat that depends on definition of wrapper. `Date` is wrapper for `long` adding methods to work with long as representation of date

Comment: @Piro If you consider `Date` as a wrapper class just because it contains `long` field then every class packaged with ME, SE, EE, etc will be considered as a wrapper class. The wrapper classes are those packaged inside `java.lang` and are called primitive wrapper classes.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat as I said, it depends on definition. You did not said you want Boxing classes for primitive types.

Comment: @Piro No! The definition of wrapper class is only one: *primitive wrapper class*. If you consider `Date` as a wrapper class then ***every class packaged with ME, SE, EE, etc will be considered as a wrapper class***

Comment: @AniketSahrawat then Option is also not valid. What about [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)?

Comment: @Piro even AtomicInteger is not considered as primitive wrapper class.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat I somehow mistook you with OP. [This is what I expect as wrapper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889160/what-is-a-wrapper-class)