# Should accept() be used only at the end of a slot?

Tags: qt

I see the `accept()` somewhat similar to a `return`, so I've been putting it a the end of my slots with no code afterwards. That is, the `accept()` "finishes" the execution of the dialog.

Nevertheless, I came across the need to close a dialog and open a new one from a slot in the first one. Therefore, what I thought was moving the `accept()` to the beginning of the slot and initializing the second dialog after it. Something like the following:

```
void FirstDialog:slotFirstDialog()
{
  accept();
  // Setup second dialog arguments
  // ...
  SecondDialog *sd = new SecondDialog();
  sd->exec();
}
```

Is this use of `accept()` valid? Is it good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd avoid it. Calling `accept()` can trigger a delayed deletion of `FirstDialog` (say, if it has the `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` flag set)<sup>1</sup>; in that case, it would be deleted in one of the first events dispatched by the nested event loop (`sd->exec()`), which would lead to go on executing code in a method of an instance that has been deleted. This is just a sample problem on the top of my head, I'm sure others can be found.

I'd probably just hide the dialog before calling `exec()` on the other, and call `accept()` after the end of the nested event loop.

```
void FirstDialog:slotFirstDialog()
{
    // Setup second dialog arguments
    // ...
    SecondDialog *sd = new SecondDialog();
    hide();
    sd->exec();
    accept();
    // NB are we leaking sd? 
}
```

---

By the way:

```
SecondDialog *sd = new SecondDialog();
sd->exec();
```

here you are allocating on the heap a dialog without a parent, so either you set the `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` or explicitly call `this->deleteLater()` inside its code, or you are leaking the dialog instance.

---

Notes:

1. and it is explicitly remarked [in the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#done)

   > As with `QWidget::close()`, `done()` deletes the dialog if the `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` flag is set.

Comment: I moved the "accept()" to the end of the function and added a "hide()" at the beginning. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. Check out also the lifetime of the second dialog: who is responsible to delete it in your code?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Can you edit your answer to add a code excerpt with my original code but "fixed" with hide() so the answer is more complete?

Comment: You were right, I was leaking memory. So it should be "SecondDialog *sd = new SecondDialog(this);". Also, I would put the "hide();" at the beginning of the function to be more "faithful" to the [wrapper design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889160/what-is-a-wrapper-class) with the "second dialog initialization" being the wrapped behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

[`QDialog::accept`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qdialog.cpp.html#_ZN7QDialog6acceptEv) calls [`QDialog::done`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/dialogs/qdialog.cpp.html#_ZN7QDialog4doneEi) with a dialog code [`Accepted`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/include/qt/QtWidgets/qdialog.h.html#QDialog::DialogCode). Here is how `QDialog::done` looks like:

```
void QDialog::done(int r)
{
    Q_D(QDialog);
    setResult(r);
    hide();
    d->close_helper(QWidgetPrivate::CloseNoEvent);
    d->resetModalitySetByOpen();
    emit finished(r);
    if (r == Accepted)
        emit accepted();
    else if (r == Rejected)
        emit rejected();
}
```

which, according to the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#accept):

> Hides the modal dialog and sets the result code to Accepted.

With this in mind, I think this is not a question of a good practice, but of what your application logic requires.

Comment: My application logic requires that one dialog opens another dialog. It's not clear to me with the code excerpt from your answer if what I did is valid or not

Comment: @Alechan, as I have already mentioned: _I think this is not a question of a good practice, but of what your application logic requires_. So I have shown you what `done` does in order to be able to decide, based on your specific application, if you need this executed in the beginning or in the end of your slot.