# Python function's parameter default value is imported from another module

Tags: python, function, default-value, anti-patterns

Let's consider the following example:

```
import module

def function(param=module.value):
    pass
```

Is it good practice to set the default value of a function argument to an identifier imported from another module? I know it works, but I am asking rather about clean code approach and possible problems. I can see here a potential vulnerability: the value of the variable imported from `module` can be mutable in next release. What do you think about that?

Comment: But why setting default value for `param` in the first place? I think it would be more clear just to pass it as parameter later when you call it: `function(module.value)`.

Comment: That's a more comment relating to the usefulness of default parameters. Default parameters are useful exactly because you don't want the caller to have to specify them (most of the times).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest setting the default to `None` then programatically test for that in your code:

```
import module

def function(param = None):
    if param is None:
        param = module.value
```

It could be that a straight assignment (which just copies a reference)  is not appropriate.

For example, you mention that the class of object could change from immutable to mutable between releases.  If that occurs then you probably need to use [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html)  rather than an assignment.

However, not all classes have their own `__deepcopy__()`, and so copying objects can be problematic.  It could be that a new object should be created using the values from the original.  It is hard to say what should be used without knowing the class of the object and what you are going to do with `param`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write [wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889160/what-is-a-wrapper-class) for your purpose. If the library change or deprecate value, you can still get the same value.

Just write a simple wrapper `moduleWrapper`

```
def getValue():
    try:
        return module.value
    except:
        return None
```

Or you can set your default value that you want and then you can set this function as param.

```
import moduleWrapper
def function(param=moduleWrapper.getValue()):
    pass
```

This way if module change, you can still get your code work.