# How to Mock HttpContext to access an extension method of IIdentity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC project, I am building unit tests for a controller to return a view.

This controller's action result builds a viewmodel, and this viewmodel's constructor calls

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.NameWithoutDomain().ToUpper();
```

Where `NameWithoutDomain` is an extension method of `IIdentity`.

Whenever I run it, I keep getting "the object cannot be found" and I'm curious how can I Mock this appropriately for unit testing?

Extension method:

```
public static class SystemWebExtension
{
    public static string NameWithoutDomain(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        return identity.Name.Split('\\').Last();
    }
}
```

Model constructor:

```
public Model()
{
    this.PreparedByUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.NameWithoutDomain().ToUpper();
    this.AuthorizedBy = true;
    this.AuthorizedByUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.NameWithoutDomain().ToUpper();
    this.IssueCredit = true;
    this.CreateUser = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CreateUser) ? Environment.UserName.ToLower() : this.CreateUser;
    this.CreateDate = this.CreateDate.HasValue ? this.CreateDate : DateTime.Now;
    this.UpdateUser = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CreateUser) ? null : Environment.UserName.ToLower();
    this.UpdateDate = this.CreateDate.HasValue ? DateTime.Now : (DateTime?) null;
}
```

Comment: Have you read [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452418/how-do-i-mock-the-httpcontext-in-asp-net-mvc-using-moq)

Comment: You could create a wrapper around the HttpContext and mock the wrapper. More about wrapper pattern is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889160/what-is-a-wrapper-class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid coupling to `HttpContext` as it is not available when unit testing.

You should explicitly inject the necessary values into the model

```
public Model(IIdentity identity) {
    this.PreparedByUser = identity.NameWithoutDomain().ToUpper();
    this.AuthorizedBy = true;
    this.AuthorizedByUser = identity.NameWithoutDomain().ToUpper();
    this.IssueCredit = true;
    this.CreateUser = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CreateUser) ? Environment.UserName.ToLower() : this.CreateUser;
    this.CreateDate = this.CreateDate.HasValue ? this.CreateDate : DateTime.Now;
    this.UpdateUser = string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CreateUser) ? null : Environment.UserName.ToLower();
    this.UpdateDate = this.CreateDate.HasValue ? DateTime.Now : (DateTime?) null;
}
```

Since using a controller, you would have access to the desired information in its properties

```
//...

var model = new Model(this.User.Identity);

return View(model);
```

And when testing, you can configure the controller via its controller context

```
//...
var username = "some username here"
var identity = new GenericIdentity(username, "");
identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username));
var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, roles: new string[] { });
var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(principal);

var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
context.Setup(_ => _.User).Returns(user);

//...

controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context.Object, new RouteData(),  controller );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't mock extension methods, you would have to mock what happens inside the extension method so that it returns the value you want.

To make sure that `NameWithoutDomain` returns what you want, you could mock `IIdentity` and make it return the username you want, like so:

```
var identityMock = new Mock<IIdentity>();
identityMock.SetupGet(x => x.Name).Returns("UsernameWithoutDomain");
```

If you want to test that `NameWithoutDomain` does what it's supposed to, which is splitting the string, then you write a separate test that calls this extension method.

As for `HttpContext`, you can just instantiate it before creating your controller, and pass it the mocked `IIdentity`, for example like this (**tested with WebAPI2**):

```
var identityMock = new Mock<IIdentity>();
identityMock.SetupGet(x => x.Name).Returns("UsernameWithoutDomain");

HttpContext.Current =
    new HttpContext(new HttpRequest(null, "http://test.com", null), new HttpResponse(null))
    {
        User = new GenericPrincipal(identityMock.Object, new[] {"Role1"})
    };

var myController = new AccountController();
```

Then when you create an instance of your controller for testing, `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` will return `UsernameWithoutDomain`. Happy testing! :-)