# Can we Say facade and Adapter are more or less same  in design patterns?

Tags: design-patterns

```
Can we Say facade and Adapter are more or less in design patterns ?
```

Wikipedia explains this as :-

```
 Adapter Converts one interface to another so that it matches what the client is 
 expecting while Facade Provides a simplified interface.
```

Looking at the UML representation in wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern and adapter pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern I am not able to distinguish much between them . Can someone explain me the major point of difference in two ?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/350404/how-do-the-proxy-decorator-adaptor-and-bridge-patterns-differ

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296299

Comment: The difference is mostly in intent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Adapter` design pattern "converts" a class interface into another that the client expect/can use. I.e. it facilitates the "cooperation" with incompatible interfaces.
I.e. *adapts* the existing interface of a class into one that the client can use.

The `Facade` design pattern offers a uniform interface for a set of interfaces of a system. It makes easier for the calling code to manipulate the system over a facade (The word facade comes from the French language, literally meaning "frontage" or "face";A facade or façade is generally one **exterior** side of a building, usually, but not always, the front. An outward appearance that is maintained to conceal a less pleasant or creditable reality).

Comment: So, would it be appropriate to speak of having an abstract class / interface that unifies access to certain functionality across various providers as a `facade`, while referring to a concrete implementation of that facade for a particular service as an `adapter`?

Comment: @Faust:No. These are 2 different patterns addressing different domains.One is not the implementation part of the other

Answer (score 2):

The `Adapter` is specifically for when you need to adapt a class to a specific interface.

The `Facade` is about hiding messy interface(s) behind a simple one that does what you need it to.

Comment: But the the only differ being implementation of a specific interface and more than 1 interface in case of facade the major one ? As far as hiding mess is concerned , i guess adapter can also do the same

Answer (score 1):

A `Facade` could be an `Adapter` and vice versa but they generally have a different intents. A `Facade` is often used in an API to lower the barrier for using more simple functionality. Whereas an `Adapter` helps bridge the gap between two incompatible interfaces that need to communicate. An `Adapter` also enables decoupling of two systems so they each only need to depend on the `Adapter` interface.