# PHP design patterns - inheritance vs adapter pattern?

Tags: php, inheritance, design-patterns, adapter, extends

I am a bit confused with the concept of adapter pattern. I find that adapter classes are very similar to extended classes that I would write usually. So, what is the **differences** between them actually?

For instance (an example from this [link](http://www.fluffycat.com/PHP-Design-Patterns/Adapter/)),

SimpleBook.php,

```
class SimpleBook {


    private $author;
    private $title;


    function __construct($author_in, $title_in) {
      $this->author = $author_in;
      $this->title  = $title_in;
    }


    function getAuthor() {return $this->author;}


    function getTitle() {return $this->title;}


  }
```

BookAdapter.php

```
include_once('SimpleBook.php');

  class BookAdapter {


    private $book;


    function __construct(SimpleBook $book_in) {
      $this->book = $book_in;
    }


    function getAuthorAndTitle() {
      return $this->book->getTitle() . ' by ' . $this->book->getAuthor();
    }


  }
```

BookExtension.php,

```
include_once('SimpleBook.php');

      class BookExtension extends SimpleBook{

        function getAuthorAndTitle() {
          return $this->getTitle() . ' by ' . $this->getAuthor();
        }


      }
```

The second solution seems a lot simpler. So is it (and **other** inheritance classes in general) considered as **adapter** class then?

Answer (score 1):

The difference relates to how the classes can be used with polymorphism.

If you use inheritance, any function that expects a `SimpleBook` will also accept a `BookExtension`, or any other class that extends `SimpleBook`. For instance, if you had:

```
function PigLatinTitle(SimpleBook $b) {
    return PigLatin($b->getTitle());
}
```

you can call this function on a `BookExtension` because it inherits the `SimpleBook::getTitle()` method.

Note that it doesn't work the other way around: a function that expects `BookExtension` won't work with `SimpleBook`. For instance, if the function calls `getAuthorAndTitle()`, that will fail if the argument is a `SimpleBook` because there's no such method there.

If you use the adapter, the two classes are independent. Functions that expect a `SimpleBook` will not accept a `BookAdapter`, and vice versa. You could not call `PigLatinTitle()` on a `BookAdapter`, because there's no `BookAdapter::getTitle()` method.

You can make the adapter work like inheritance by adding a `__call()` magic method to `BookAdapter`, and then re-calling the method on `$this->book`:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments) {
    return call_user_func_array(array($this->book, $name), $arguments);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am a bit confused with `If you use inheritance, any function that expects a SimpleBook will also accept a BookExtension, or any other class that extends SimpleBook.` I thought in inheritance, the parent class does not know anything about its children classes. So when I use the parent class on its own, I am not using its children classes, right?

Comment: The parent class doesn't need to know anything about the children, it's automatic. They inherit the parent's methods.

Comment: ok. so if I `expect` SimpleBook only, how would I `also accept` BookExtension? they are actually `independent` (of cos BookExtension depends on SimpleBook, just as BookAdapter depends on SimpleBook).

Comment: See the example I added.

Comment: sorry I can understand about the adapter you try explain. not sure about the inheritance though... where do you place this `PigLatineTitle`? in `SimpleBook` or in `BookExtension`?

Comment: It's not in either of them, it's just an ordinary function.

Answer (score 1):

You can read this interesting question about adapter. Most likely its a wrapper pattern with inner and outer class:[How do the Proxy, Decorator, Adapter, and Bridge Patterns differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350404/how-do-the-proxy-decorator-adapter-and-bridge-patterns-differ).