# What's the pattern name for wrapping access to static methods/variables?

Tags: java, design-patterns, proxy, wrapper

Following on from the question [How do the Proxy, Decorator, Adapter, and Bridge Patterns differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350404/how-do-the-proxy-decorator-adapter-and-bridge-patterns-differ), how would you describe the following pattern which I've needed to implement on several occasions?

The scenario is that I'm referencing a static method or variable from a third-party class, but I want to hide it behind an interface so that I can mock it for testing.

For example, in Java the commons-lang library has a SystemUtils class with constants IS_OS_WINDOWS etc. I want to run tests which are independent of the underlying OS and mimic various OSs, so I wrap access to the constant as follows:

```
interface ISystemUtils {
    boolean isOsWindows();
}

class SystemUtilsImpl implements ISystemUtils {
    @Override
    public boolean isOsWindows() {
        return SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS;
    }
}
```

Is this a Proxy, a generic "wrapper", or something else?

Answer (score 5):

This is called a [Facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern):

> A facade is an object that provides a simplified interface to a larger
>   body of code, such as a class library. A facade can:
>
> - make a software library easier to use, understand and test, since the
>     facade has convenient methods for common tasks;
> - make the library more readable, for the same reason
> - reduce dependencies of outside code on the inner workings of a library, since most code uses the facade, thus allowing more flexibility in developing the system
> - wrap a poorly designed collection of APIs with a single well-designed API.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer @adriaan.  Facade "feels" right although my understanding was that it usually (always?) involved covering elements of _multiple_ underlying classes.  However my example arguably covers most of the above bullet points, particularly the first one.

Comment: @Gendarme Fixed the layout of the Facade link, tnx

Answer (score 1):

The Facade pattern is a good answer, although I do agree that it normally (in my experience at least) expose a number of different operations/classes.  With that said, a number of other patterns can also serve the same purpose - Proxy would likely be my first choice, but Adaptor or [Mediator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) could also be a good fit.  Another term for this that you may also come across is a "[delegate](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077357/learn-java/delegates.html)".