# Design pattern for transformer involving third party library

Tags: java, design-patterns

Suppose there is a third party library containing base class Transformer and concrete implementations TransformerA and TransformerB.

I need to write parallel classes for TransformerA and TransformerB outputting class say TransformerNew

```java
public class TransformerAConverter {
  public TransformerNew convert(TransformerA transformerA) {
    // conversion logic
  }
}

public class TransformerBConverter {
  public TransformerNew convert(TransformerB transformerB) {
    // conversion logic
  }
}
```

I need to write following function:

```
public TransformerNew[] process(Transformer[] transformers) {
}
```

How can I achieve this without instanceof or explicit type casting. I have tried using visitor pattern but unable to express it.

Comment: What's the problem with `instanceof`?

Comment: What exactly does _conversion logic_ mean? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350404/how-do-the-proxy-decorator-adapter-and-bridge-patterns-differ/350471#350471) might help.

Comment: @dur : There could be 10-15 such transformers and I do not wish to use so many instanceof.

Comment: @AndrewS : There would be TransformerNew as base class with TransformerNewA will read getters from TransformerA and populate fields in TransformerNewA according to my own custom logic. Basically downstream I wish to use my custom representation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using `Strategy` pattern here. The two transformers would be the Transformer `strategy` here. You may organize the code like this. `Visitor` won't fit in here, since it is used to decouple the traversal logic from the underneath data structure or representation.

```
public class TransformerConverter {
    private final Transformer transformerStrategy,

    public TransformerConverter(Transformer strategy) {
        this.transformerStrategy = strategy;
    }

    public TransformerNew convert() {
        // use the strategy to achieve the conversion.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the comments - that sounds like the Facade pattern might be useful.  For example, given this interface:

```
public interface TransformerNew {
    public int getInterestingValue();
}
```

Then have a few implementations:

```
public class TransformerNewA implements TransformerNew {
    private final TransformerA a;

    public TransformerNewA(TransformerA a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int getInterestingValue() {
        return a.getSomeValue() + a.getSomeOtherValue();
    }

}
```

and

```
public class TransformerNewB implements TransformerNew {
    private final TransformerB b;

    public TransformerNewB(TransformerB b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int getInterestingValue() {
        return b.getFirstPart() + b.getSecondPart();
    }

}
```

So there's really no conversion here - just wrapping the 3rd party type, and providing a common (hopefully simpler) interface for downstream use.