# What is the difference between the template method and the strategy patterns?

Tags: design-patterns, strategy-pattern, template-method-pattern

Can someone please explain to me what is the difference between the template method pattern and the strategy pattern is?

As far as I can tell they are 99% the same - the only difference being
that the template method pattern has an abstract class as the base
class whereas the strategy class uses an interface that is implemented
by each concrete strategy class.

However, as far as the *client* is concerned they are consumed in exactly the same way - is this correct?

Comment: This post in SO has a better answer for the same question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464524/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bridge-pattern-and-the-strategy-pattern

Comment: The question gob00st linked to is the difference between strategy and bridge. It's not the answer to this question at all.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

The main difference between the two is when the concrete algorithm is chosen.

With the **Template method pattern** this happens at *compile-time* by *subclassing* the template.  Each subclass provides a different concrete algorithm by implementing the template's abstract methods.  When a client invokes methods of the template's external interface the template calls its abstract methods (its internal interface) as required to invoke the algorithm.

```
class ConcreteAlgorithm : AbstractTemplate
{
    void DoAlgorithm(int datum) {...}
}

class AbstractTemplate
{
    void run(int datum) { DoAlgorithm(datum); }

    virtual void DoAlgorithm() = 0; // abstract
}
```

In contrast, the **Strategy pattern** allows an algorithm to be chosen at *runtime* by *containment*.  The concrete algorithms are implemented by separate classes or functions which are passed to the strategy as a parameter to its constructor or to a setter method.  Which algorithm is chosen for this parameter can vary dynamically based on the program's state or inputs.

```
class ConcreteAlgorithm : IAlgorithm
{
    void DoAlgorithm(int datum) {...}
}

class Strategy
{
    Strategy(IAlgorithm algo) {...}

    void run(int datum) { this->algo.DoAlgorithm(datum); }
}
```

### In summary:

- Template method pattern: **compile-time** algorithm selection by **subclassing**
- Strategy pattern: **run-time algorithm** selection by **containment**

Comment: Both patterns support runtime selection of the algorithm used (for Template Method, you would do something like `if (config.useAlgoA) impl = new AlgoA() else impl = new AlgoB()`) so this answer is incorrect.

Comment: Sure you could do that but then you're not using the Template Pattern.  In fact, that's almost exactly what the code creating the Strategy instance will look like!

Comment: -1, I think this answer (though not completely wrong), misses the point where the real differences are. @tvanfosson's answer is much better.

Comment: Wrong. This is a common mistake about confusing the Strategy with the Template Method pattern.
The Strategy is indeed about replacing behavior. And this can be done at compile time or at runtime, too.
Whereas the Template Method is about allowing specific steps in an algorithm to be replaced without modifying the structure of the algorithm.
See also: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method

Comment: @tvanfosson answer's below should be the accepted answer. 
This one is actually confusing the Strategy with the Template Method pattern.
Strategy: replace behavior
Template Method: provide extension points so callers can provide certain steps of an algorithm.
I suggested edits to the answer above but it was rejected. The reviewer obviously doesn't understand the difference between the two patterns either.

Comment: @Karoly Nyisztor They both can "replace behavior" and "provide extension points." Whether something's a behavior or an extension, it's really up to the context of where you apply a given pattern. You can call each subclass of the template method pattern a "strategy" too, or call each strategy class in the strategy pattern an "extension," it's just wording. Fact of the matter is they do the same thing EXCEPT the difference that this answer mentions. So this is the right answer.

Comment: A concrete algorithm is chosen the same way for both patterns. The choice is made by invoking `new ConcreteAlgorithm1()` versus `new ConcreteAlgorithm2()`. Obviously the choice happens at runtime (making an algorithm choice at compile time would mean hard-coding it). The main difference between the two is how the concrete algorithm is implemented. Is it implemented as a subclass or as a separate interface? The former is a Template. The latter is a Strategy. The difference can be summarized as composition vs inheritance, which is a common theme of the GoF book.

Comment: "_Favor composition over inheritance_" indicates we should use Strategy more often than Template Method.

Answer (score 186):

The template pattern is used when a particular operation has some invariant behavior(s) that can be defined in terms of other varying primitive behaviors.  The abstract class defines the invariant behavior(s), while the implementing classes defined the dependent methods.

In a strategy, the behavior implementations are independent -- each implementing class defines the behavior and there is no code shared between them.  Both are behavioral patterns and, as such, are consumed in much the same way by clients.  Typically strategies have a single public method -- the `execute()` method, whereas templates may define a set of public methods as well as a set of supporting private primitives that subclasses must implement.

The two patterns could easily be used together.  You might have a strategy pattern where several implementations belong to a family of strategies implemented using a template pattern.

Comment: This sounds right to me, however why does [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) mentions that "strategy pattern is for an algorithm's behavior to be selected at runtime"? It could also be used for selecting algorithm's behavior at compile time, just like the template method? Am I missing something?

Comment: @BornToCode I would assume what they are talking about is choosing a particular strategy at run time. For example, there are are several ways of numerically finding the roots of an equation.  Depending on the problem domain or the data you might choose Newton-Raphson, Euler, or some other strategy for solving the equation.  Each one of those is a strategy. The larger algorithm, of which solving the equation is one part, chooses the strategy to employ based on some quality of the problem.

Comment: Yes, but it's not like strategy pattern should be used ONLY for those cases? I mean if I only need to select algorithm's behavior at compile time should I still use strategy pattern, or it wasn't meant to be used that way?

Comment: @BornToCode I would say that a strategy is most useful when the choice is dynamic.  Template is basically a way of building up different, related behaviors for known. You'd use some strategy (though not the strategy pattern necessarily) for choosing which templated behavior to employ. For example, product inheritance - you'd create a base product, add features for different products. Choosing which product type (class) to instantiate might depend on which tables/views it's loaded from.  Strategy pattern doesn't really come into play there.

Comment: What about this - each product has a list of features and different classes using the products would like to have this list of features sorted in a specific order? Those classes would pass another FeaturesSortingStrategy and this is all done at compile time. I thought strategy could fit this more than template, What is your opinion about such scenario?

Comment: @BornToCode it's not an either/or thing, it's yes-and.  Apply the pattern where it's appropriate, combine patterns where it's useful.

Comment: This is the right answer! The currently accepted answer is nothing but a common mistake of confusing the Strategy and the Template Method pattern.

Answer (score 32):

[image: Difference between Strategy and Template Method Pattern Strategy vs Template method]

---

### Similarities

Strategy and Template method patterns have a lot of similarities between them. Both Strategy and Template method patterns can be used for satisfying the Open-Closed Principle and making the software module easy to extend without changing its code. Both patterns represent separation of generic functionality from the detailed implementation of that functionality. However, they differ a little in terms of granularity they offer.

---

### Differences

Here are some of the differences I have observed while studying these two patterns:

1. In Strategy, the coupling between the client and strategy is more
   loose whereas in Template Method, the two modules are more tightly
   coupled.
2. In Strategy, mostly an interface is used though abstract class can
   also be used depending on the situation, and concrete class is not
   used whereas in Template method mostly abstract class or concrete
   class is used, interface is not used.
3. In Strategy pattern, generally entire behaviour of the class is
   represented in terms of an interface, on the other hand, Template method is used
   for reducing code duplication and the boilerplate code is defined in
   base framework or abstract class. In Template Method, there can even be a concrete class
   with default implementation.
4. In simple words, you can change the entire strategy (algorithm) in
   Strategy pattern, however, in Template method, only some things
   change (parts of algorithm) and rest of the things remain unchanged. In Template Method, the invariant steps are implemented in an abstract base class, while the
   variant steps are either given a default implementation, or no
   implementation at all. In Template method, the component designer
   mandates the required steps of an algorithm, and the ordering of the
   steps, but allows the component client to extend or replace some
   number of these steps.

---

Image is taken from the [bitesized](http://www.bitesizedcsharp.com/) blog.

Comment: is it possible to use template for steps/process and strategy for swapping specific step/process?

Comment: @BIDude, if you want to swap only some steps and enforce other steps, use template. To allow swapping of all steps, use strategy.

Answer (score 31):

I think the Class-Diagrams of both pattern are showing the differences.

**Strategy**
Encapsulates an algorithm inside a class
[Link to image](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Diagrams/strategy.gif)
[image]

**Template Method**
Defer the exact steps of an algorithm to a subclass
[Link to Image](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Diagrams/template.gif)
[image]

Answer (score 27):

You probably mean template method pattern.
You are right, they serve very similar needs.
I would say it is better to use template method in cases when you have a "template" algorithm having defined steps where subclasses override these steps to change some details.
In case of strategy, you need to create an interface, and instead of inheritance you are using delegation. I would say it is a bit more powerful pattern and maybe better in accordance to DIP - dependency inversion principles. It is more powerful because you clearly define a new abstraction of strategy - a way of doing something, which does not apply to template method. So, if this abstraction makes sense - use it. However, using template method may give you simpler designs in simple cases, which is also important.
Consider which words fit better: do you have a template algorithm? Or is the key thing here that you have an abstraction of strategy - new way of doing something

Example of a template method:

```
Application.main()
{
Init();
Run();
Done();
}
```

Here you inherit from application and substitute what exactly will be done on init, run and done.

Example of a strategy:

```
array.sort (IComparer<T> comparer)
```

Here, when writing a comparer, you do not inherit from an array. Array delegates the comparison algorithm to a comparer.

Answer (score 23):

Inheritance versus aggregation (is-a versus has-a).  It's two ways to achieve the same goal.

This question shows some of trade-offs between choices: [Inheritance vs. Aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269496/inheritance-vs-aggregation)

Answer (score 16):

Both are very similar, and both are consumed by the client code in similar ways. Unlike what the most popular answer above says, **both allow algorithm selection at run-time**.

The difference between the two is that while the *strategy pattern* allows different implementations to use completely different ways of the achieving the desired outcome, the *template method pattern* specifies an overarching algorithm (the "template" method) which is be used to achieve the result -- the only choice left to the specific implementations (sub-classes) are certain details of the said template method. This is done by having the the template method make call(s) to one or more *abstract* methods which are overridden (i.e. implemented) by the sub-classes, unlike the template method which itself is not abstract and not overridden by the sub-classes.

The client code makes a call to the template method using a reference/pointer of the abstract class type pointing to an instance of one of the concrete sub classes which can be determined at run time just like while using the Strategy Pattern.

Answer (score 9):

*Template Method:*

1. It's based on *inheritance*
2. Defines skeleton of algorithm which can't be changed by sub classes.
3. Only certain operations can be overridden in sub classes
4. Parent class completely *controls the algorithm*
5. Binding is done at compile time

*Strategy:*

1. It's based on *delegation/composition*
2. *It changes guts of the object* by modifying method behaviour
3. It's used to *switch between family of algorithms*
4. It changes the behaviour of the object at run time by completely
5. Binding is done at run time

Have a look at [Template method](http://www.journaldev.com/1763/template-method-design-pattern-in-java) and [Strategy](http://www.journaldev.com/1754/strategy-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial) articles for better understanding.

Related posts:

[Template design pattern in JDK, could not find a method defining set of methods to be executed in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559360/template-design-pattern-in-jdk-could-not-find-a-method-defining-set-of-methods/38740810#38740810)

[Real World Example of the Strategy Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370258/real-world-example-of-the-strategy-pattern/35180265#35180265)

Answer (score 4):

No, they are not necessarily consumed in the same way. The "template method" pattern is a way of providing "guidance" to future implementers. You are telling them, "All Person objects must have a Social Security Number" (that's a trivial example but it gets the idea across correctly).

The strategy pattern allows **multiple** possible implementations to be switched in and out. It is not (usually) implemented through inheritance, but instead by letting the caller pass in the desired implementation. An example might be allowing a ShippingCalculator to be provided with one of several different ways of calculating taxes (a NoSalesTax implementation, and a PercentageBasedSalesTax implementation perhaps).

So, sometimes, the **client** will actually tell the object which strategy to use. As in

```
myShippingCalculator.CalculateTaxes(myCaliforniaSalesTaxImpl);
```

But the client would never do that for an object that was based on Template Method. In fact, the client might not even know an object is based on Template Method. Those abstract methods in the Template Method pattern might even be protected, in which case the client wouldn't even know they exist.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/695871/Comparison-of-Template-and-Strategy-Design-Pattern) article. It explains the differences on a real case example.

**Quote from the article**

> "*As one can see implementing classes also depend upon the template
>   method class. This dependency causes to change the template method if
>   one wants to change some of the steps of the algorithm. On the other
>   side strategy completely encapsulates the algorithm. it gives the
>   implementing classes to completely define an algorithm. Therefore if
>   any change arrives one does need to change the code for previously
>   written classes. This was the primary reason I choose strategy for
>   designing up the classes.*
>
> *One feature of template method is that template method controls the
>   algorithm. Which can be a good thing in other situation but in my
>   problem this was restricting me to design the classes. On the other
>   side strategy does not control the steps of an algorithm which enables
>   me to add completely different conversion methods. Hence in my case
>   strategy helps me for implementation.*
>
> *One drawback of strategy is that there is too much code redundancy and
>   less code sharing. As it is obvious in the presented example of this
>   article I have to repeat the same code in four classes again and
>   again. Therefore it is hard to maintain because if the implementation
>   of our system such as step 4 which is common to all is changed then I
>   will have to update this in all 5 classes. On the other side, in
>   template method, I can only change the superclass and the changes are
>   reflected into the sub classes. Therefore template method gives a very
>   low amount of redundancy and high amount of code sharing among the
>   classes.*
>
> *Strategy also allows changing the algorithm at run-time. In template
>   method one will have to re-initialize the object. This feature of
>   strategy provide large amount of flexibility. From design point of
>   view one has to prefer composition over inheritance. Therefore using
>   strategy pattern also became the primary choice for development."*

Answer (score 3):

In strategy pattern subclasses are running the show and they control the algorithm. Here code is duplicated across the subclasses. The knowledge of the algorithm and how to implement it is distributed over many classes.

In template pattern, base class has algorithm. It maximizes the reuse among the subclasses. Since algorithm lies in one place, base class protects it.

Answer (score 2):

The Template pattern is similar to the Strategy pattern. These two patterns differ in scope and in methodology.

Strategy is used to allow callers to vary an entire algorithm, like how to calculate different types of tax, while Template Method is used to vary steps in an algorithm. Because of this, Strategy is more coarsely grained. The Template allows finer-grained controls in the sequent of operations, and yet allows the implementations of these details to vary.

The other main difference is that Strategy uses delegation while Template Method uses inheritance. In Strategy, the algorithm is delegated to the another xxxStrategy class that the subject will have a reference to, but with Template you subclass the base and override methods to make changes.

from http://cyruscrypt.blogspot.com/2005/07/template-vs-strategy-patterns.html

Answer (score 2):

## Template Pattern:

Template method is about letting subclasses redefine certain steps of the algorithm, without changing the main structure and steps of the algorithm, defined in the base class.
Template pattern usually uses inheritance, so a generic implementation of algorithms can be provided in the base class, which the subclass might choose to override if needed.

```
public abstract class RobotTemplate {
    /* This method can be overridden by a subclass if required */
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting....");
    }

    /* This method can be overridden by a subclass if required */
    public void getParts() {
        System.out.println("Getting parts....");
    }

    /* This method can be overridden by a subclass if required */
    public void assemble() {
        System.out.println("Assembling....");
    }

    /* This method can be overridden by a subclass if required */
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Testing....");
    }

    /* This method can be overridden by a subclass if required */
    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("Stopping....");
    }

    /*
     * Template algorithm method made up of multiple steps, whose structure and
     * order of steps will not be changed by subclasses.
     */
    public final void go() {
        start();
        getParts();
        assemble();
        test();
        stop();
    }
}


/* Concrete subclass overrides template step methods as required for its use */
public class CookieRobot extends RobotTemplate {
    private String name;

    public CookieRobot(String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    @Override
    public void getParts() {
        System.out.println("Getting a flour and sugar....");
    }

    @Override
    public void assemble() {
        System.out.println("Baking a cookie....");
    }

    @Override
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Crunching a cookie....");
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Note in the above code, the go() algorithm steps will always be the same, but the subclasses might define a different recipe for performing a particular step.

## Strategy Pattern:

Strategy pattern is about letting client selects concrete algorithms implementation at runtime. All algorithms are isolated and independent, but implement a common interface, and there is no notion of defining particular steps within the algorithm.

```
/**
 * This Strategy interface is implemented by all concrete objects representing an
 * algorithm(strategy), which lets us define a family of algorithms.
 */
public interface Logging {
    void write(String message);
}

/**
 * Concrete strategy class representing a particular algorithm.
 */
public class ConsoleLogging implements Logging {

    @Override
    public void write(String message) {
        System.out.println(message); 
    }

}

/**
 * Concrete strategy class representing a particular algorithm.
 */
public class FileLogging implements Logging {

    private final File toWrite;

    public FileLogging(final File toWrite) {
        this.toWrite = toWrite;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(String message) {
        try {
            final FileWriter fos = new FileWriter(toWrite);
            fos.write(message);
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

For full source code, check out my github [repository](https://github.com/sahmed10315/Design-Patterns-Java/tree/master/Behavioral%20Patterns).

Answer (score 2):

> Strategy Design Pattern

- Supports composition.
- Provides you the flexibility to change the behavior of object at runtime.
- Less coupling between the client code and the solution/algorithm code.

> Template Method Design Pattern

- Favours inheritance over composition
- Define algorithm in your base class. Individual pieces of algorithm can be customized in child classes.

Answer (score 2):

Both of them are different techniques to achieve the same result, so question is to use which when.

- If you are using a framework or library which you do not have access to the source code and you want to change some behaviors of a class, so you have to go for Template Method. That means inheritance simply.
- If you are developing a class and it is obvious that some parts of the logic needs to be implemented differently to handle various situations, take the Strategy pattern. Strategy is more SOLID than the Template Method. It covers both Dependency Inversion and Open/Close principles. So it is extendable and also easily testable.
- If you are developing a class and you do not know what changes will happen in the future, divide your logic into separate and single responsible functions as much as possible. Just that. (Neither Template Method nor Strategy).

Answer (score 0):

Strategy is exposed as an Interface and template method as the Abstract Class. This is typically used a lot in frameworks. 
e.g. 
Spring framework's MessageSource class is a strategy interface for resolving messages. Client uses particular implementation (strategy) of this interface.

And the abstract implementation of the same interface AbstractMessageSource, which has common implementation of resolving messages and exposes resolveCode() abstract method so that sub-classes can implement them in their ways. AbstractMessageSource is an example of template method.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.7.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractMessageSource.html

Answer (score 0):

In the template method of this design pattern, one or more algorithm steps can be overridden by subclasses to allow differing behaviors while ensuring that the overarching algorithm is still followed(Wiki).

The pattern name Template method means what it is. Say we have a method CalculateSomething() and we want to template this method. This method will be declared in the base class a non virtual method. Say the method looks like this.

```
CalculateSomething(){
    int i = 0;
    i = Step1(i);
    i++;
    if (i> 10) i = 5;
    i = Step2(i);
    return i;
```

}
Step1 and Step2 method implementation can be given by derived classes.

In Strategy Pattern there is no implementation provided by the base (This is the reason why the base is really an interface in the class diagram)

The classic example is sorting. Based on the number of objects needs to be sorted the appropriate algorithm class(merge, bubble, quick etc.) is created and the entire algorithm is encapsulated in each class.

Now can we implement the sorting as a template method? Certainly you can, but you wont find much/any commonality to be abstracted out and placed in the base implementation. So it defeats the purpose of template method pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think the major difference is that with template you need an algorithm that does something, but lets say in the middle of that algorithm you want to run different behaviours so you can send an implementation of an interface to make that algorithm dynamically in runtime.

but with strategy you have actually totally different algorithms executions no just a variant of the algorithm, then you chose which algo to run, but template you have just one algo with variants.

At the end you can implement as you want and use template as strategy and viceversa but I see a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Template method pattern is good at clarify the overall algorithm steps, however Strategy pattern is suitable for flexibility and reusibility, so you can combine strageties together if you need, e.g: many functional interfaces in jdk8 like `Comparator.reversed().thenComparing(Comparator)` is a role of strategy.

Template method pattern is focus more high cohesion, but Strategy pattern is loosely coupled with context object for separating concerns.

Strategy is easy to maintain since the context has no knowlege about concrete strategies, whenever the mainly algorithm is changed in context doesn't affect the strategies. On the other hand, if you changed the sckeleton of the algorithm in abstract template class maybe affect its subclasses to upgrade.