# Can two strategies in a strategy pattern use the same code? Does this make it a template pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I have a program to transfer files from one computer to another which uses 4 different classes A, B, C and D. My program creates an object and uses A and B to check and validate the files to be sent. Now I have to add an additional transfer technique. I guess using strategy pattern would be the best case scenario since we can choose either of the transfer techniques. But I wanted to ask whether or not can we use classes A and B to validate the transfer of files in my strategy also? Does this make it a template design pattern rather than a strategy design pattern?

Comment: Yes, you can reuse the validation. No, that does not create a Template. The difference between Strategy and Template is composition vs inheritance, respectively.

Comment: So here what would be the advised pattern? I want my two transfer techniques to be loosely coupled. Should I use inheritance or composition?

Comment: That is a matter of opinion and context, but you can read more about the difference here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/669271/what-is-the-difference-between-the-template-method-and-the-strategy-patterns. Start without design patterns and solve the problem in whatever way is clean and readable.

Answer (score 0):

If your strategies are quite complex and have a common schema (i.e. the validation part) you can have a strategytemplate which does the validation, than every concrete strategy class does the rest:

```
public interface ITransferFileStrategy {
     bool TransferFile(File f);
}

public abstract class TransferFileStrategyTemplate {
     public bool TransferFile(File f) {
         if (!ValidateFile(f)) return false;
         return TransferFileInner(f);
     }
     protected virtual bool ValidateFile(File f) {
        //implement it here
     }

     protected abstract bool TransferFileInner(File f);
}

public class TransferFileStrategyA {
    protected override bool TransferFileInner(File f) { ... }
}
```

you could even use a nested strategy (IValidationStrategy) in TransferFileStrategyTemplate to handle the validation if you know that there will be different kind of validations.