# NDepend How to write query for parallel inheritance hierarchies

Tags: ndepend

What is the query for getting the classes which are using parallel inheritance hierarchies?

Comment: I assume you refer to "parallel inheritance hierarchies" as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434577 This is an interesting question to mull over. What would be the criteria you'd use to match the hierarchies? Similar class names? another?

Comment: My intention is that, but instead matching by names, is it possible to do match with fields(similar structure)?

Comment: Please be more explicit about "match with fields". Do you mean that parallel base classes must have same number of instance fields with same name and same visibility?

Comment: Yes, matching a name will be very rare scenario. But if the instance fields is more or less matching (~2 fields) and the type matches exactlly...