# Maintaining a parallel class hierarchy in C++

Tags: java, c++, oop, inheritance

There is a certain class hierarchy and I would like to have another hierarchy having a class corresponding to every class in the former hierarchy.  Note that the structure of the second hierarchy isn't as neat or as similar as the original hierarchy.

As an illustration, I have a `Game` hierarchy that has different games like `CricketGame`, `TestCricketGame`, `BasketBallGame` etc., and there **must** exist a `CricketGamesContainer`, `TestCricketGamesContainer` and `BasketBallGamesContainer` in the other hierarchy. Is there a way of ensuring that for every class in the `Game` hierarchy the programmer is forced to write a class in the `Container` hierarchy? That is, say, the code doesn't compile otherwise.

Comment: Sounds quite unlikely that you could make the compiler enforce this.. For clarity, are you doing this in java or c++? Or do you not care as long as it is possible using one of them?

Comment: As I've stated in the question heading, it's in C++ :) And we will have to stick to that.

Comment: If at all possible, avoid the parallel hierarchies altogether, as [outlined in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696350/avoiding-parallel-inheritance-hierarchies).