# How to inject Parent class in other classes so that It picks the child class based on passed model?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have the following classes in Java

```
class A which is inherited by class A1 and A2

A has method run and both A1, A2 are overriding this method

Another model class B

B has JSON subtypes B1 and B2 (child classes)
```

What I want to achieve now is if I run

```
InstanceOfA.run(B) where B is a reference to B1 subtype, it should execute A1's run method

and If I run InstanceOfA.run(B) where B is a reference to B2 subtype, It should execute A2's run method.
```

InstanceOfA is an instance of A.

If this is possible, I can inject A using @Inject annotation in all other classes (where it is required) and don't need to pass actual implementations.

Any other solution to do is also welcome.

Comment: Basic concept of inheritance is that parent does not know child. Parent can be interface, abstract or fully implemented class. With that ```class A``` should never know existence of A1 and A2.

Comment: It looks like you have [parallel inheritance hierarchies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696350/avoiding-parallel-inheritance-hierarchies).