# Is Bridge Pattern same as the Provider Pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

Is the Bridge Pattern same as the Provider Pattern. I did not see the Provider Pattern listed in the GoF book

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a difference is that a provider pattern would potentially encapsulate many bridges?

I am also asking myself the same question and finding it hard to see the difference.

I see provider pattern as basically being the strategy pattern.

A question that may help and clear up my confusion

[When do you use the Bridge Pattern? How is it different from Adapter pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319728/when-do-you-use-the-bridge-pattern)

IE yes they look similar in examples but their purpose is different.

Answer (score 0):

I would say they are "very similar," consider Steven Metsker's Design Patterns in C#: he provides an implementation of the Bridge pattern for Database Drivers on pg. 71.  As I read it, it looks like the Provider Pattern in Bridge Clothing.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with the Provider pattern. The purpose of the Bridge pattern is to de-couple abstractions from their corresponding implementations. Simplistic eg code:

```
class Abstraction
{
  IBridge _bridge;
  public Abstraction(IBridge implementation) { _bridge=implementation; }
  public DoStuff() { _bridge.DoStuff(); }
}

interface IBridge
{
  void DoStuff();
}

class BridgeA : IBridge
{
  void DoStuff() {...}
}

class BridgeB : IBridge
{
  void DoStuff() {...}
}
```