# Bridge pattern in java without abstract class

Tags: java, design-patterns, bridge

I am trying to learn Bridge pattern. So far every page I have referred to, has one abstraction as interface and other as abstract class. Abstract class holds a reference to interface. I was wondering, if I replace abstract class with interface and have a reference of second interface in each impl class, would that still make sense in context of Bridge pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the composition relationship from the abstract class down to its implementation, then you have an Adapter rather than a Bridge.

If you have multiple Adapters all composing a common interface, then it probably makes sense to pull that composition relationship up to an abstraction, i.e. a Bridge again.

See also: [Adapter vs Bridge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067236/1371329)