# What is benefit of Bridge Pattern

Tags: c#, java, php, asp.net, design-patterns

When I want to learn something new, I ask myself, what I lost when I don't learn that thing. I  am going to learn some design patterns and everything is good. But when I arrived to [Bridge Design Pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternBridge.aspx) I fell in problem. Really I can not imagine when to use this design pattern. And I know there is another links in google and stackoverflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319728/when-do-you-use-the-bridge-pattern).

But can anyone say that, what we lost if we forget `Bridge Design Pattern` and skip try this pattern?

Comment: this looks like an extended factory pattern IMHO

Comment: You can see [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319728/when-do-you-use-the-bridge-pattern

Comment: @mjavadlatify  I previously saw that link. Unfortunately that doesn't help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Bridge pattern is simply noticing a couple of converging responsibilities and separating them. I'll use The Gang of Four (TGF)'s example because I think its a really good one:

You have a Window interface, with two subclasses: XWindow (based on the X Window Manager) and PMWindow (based on IBM's Presentation Manager (PM) Window Manager... which I've never heard of).

ie:

```
interface Window {}
class XWindow : Window {}
class PMWindow : Window {}
```

The problem with continuing in our traditional inheritance approach is that if you specialize Window on an aspect other than its platform dependence (ie, you have some responsibility that is orthogonal to the one you created the inheritance tree to support), you need to use the bridge pattern, otherwise your class hierarchy will grow in depth geometrically. I think a good way to think of bridge as a combination of inheritance and composition.

That's pretty wordy. Going back to the TGF example: what if you want an IconWindow and a TransientWindow (something like a glass pane). The concept of "Icon vs Transient" and "PM vs X" are two orthogonal ideas, but they're both trying to get on the same inheritance tree. If don't use the bridge pattern, what you'll have to do is create two new interfaces inheriting from the first, and a slew of classes beneath them:

```
interface Window {}
class XWindow : Window {}
class PMWindow : Window {}
interface IconWindow : Window {}
class XIconWindow : XWindow, IconWindow {}
class PMIconWindow : PMWindow, IconWindow {}
interface TransientWindow : Window {}
class XTransientWIndow : XWindow, TransientWindow {}
class PMTransientWindow : PMWindow, TransientWindow {}
```

With the bridge pattern you would separate those two responsibilities onto two inheritance trees:

```
interface Window {}
class IconWindow : Window {} //this class...
class TransientWindow : Window {} //and this one will keep a private reference to aWindowImp
interface WindowImp: Window {}
class XWindowImp : WindowImp {}
class PMWindowImp : WindowImp {}
```

Much cleaner, much better responsibility segregation, and much easier to write and consume!

I *believe* that this design problem and the oddities of even the bridge object tree were actually some of the issues driving the design of Mix-ins in Scala. Using C++'s multiple inheritance, you'd statically couple any implementations to their windowing system. In other words, you'd have the same number of types as the non-bridge pattern but they'd probably be empty classes and you can of course refer to them by the abstraction, which makes it fairly easy to consume.

Comment: It is good example, however can you describe what is difference between `Bridge` and `Strategy` pattern? They look similar!

Comment: Thank you i think your example is good for understanding `Bridge Pattern`.

Comment: I really think an example everyone can relate to would be more appropriate (lots of people aren't even familiar with these dates technologies)

Answer (score 3):

The advantages of a bridge are that abstraction and implementation be decoupled. The implementation is also changed dynamically at run time and the extensibility of abstraction and implementation is improved.

By specifying a parameter in the generation of an abstraction, the implementation can be chosen also for the implementation of the client is completely hidden. A strong increase in the number of classes can be avoided.

[image: Wiki UML]

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Check this out http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternBridge.aspx#_self1

Comment: Imagine that you have a class which accesses to a method in your abstract class which your class wants to implement.
The bridge-pattern you can now change the implementation during the term and are therefore it's not bound to the method of abstract class

Comment: @Coder I saw that links. It does not help me.

Comment: Thank you @WEBALDO.at. can you show in your example how `List` and `ListImpl` can changed dynamically at runtime?

Comment: Here you can see some good examples:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns?rq=1