# Factory Pattern and Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, design-patterns

In my C#, MVVM application, I took over code that is generating a class object. Given the requirement that I was handed, I might need to create multiple objects based on a value. So I decided to refactor class generation by using the factory pattern and that worked for that requirement. As I proceeded in the task more requirement have come up, which includes creating an object not only by the original string variable but also by a boolean variable. In addition, to those variables, a parameter needs to be passed into the object, which I think I should do by dependency injection. My question is should I be using the Factory pattern at this point or something else. How do I incorporate the boolean variable and the parameter in whatever recommended design pattern. The code example of what I am using is below.

```
 public abstract class PivotRequestFactory
 {
    public abstract PivotRequest GetPivotRequest();
 }

public class ConcretePivotRequestFactory : PivotRequestFactory
{

    public ConcretePivotRequestFactory()
    {

    }
    public override PivotRequest GetPivotRequest()
    {
        try
        {

            return new PivotRequest();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
}

private PivotRequest GetPivotRequest(string DataSetName)
    {
        PivotRequestFactory factory = null;
        try
        {
            switch (DataSetName)
            {
                case DatasetNames.Default:
                    if (IsTrue) { factory = new ConcretePivotRequestFactory(); }
                    else { factory = new ConcretePivotRequestFactory2); }
                    break;
                case DatasetNames.SoSo:
                    if (IsTrue) { factory = new ConcretePivotRequestFactory3(); }
                    else { factory = new ConcretePivotRequestFactory4(); }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        return factory.GetPivotRequest();
    }
```

Comment: Just curious: what is idea behind catching an exception and re-throwing it again?

Comment: What does `GetPivotRequest(string)` belong to, in your example it is just floating there alone as a private method?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using or not using a factory or even violating a given pattern in some way, in fact that's the wrong question altogether. The right question is: will this make my code easier to understand? NEVER USE A PATTERN JUST TO USE A PATTERN!!!

Comment: @Fabio I am asking about what pattern I should use the exception has nothing to do with this, I put in a try catch and didnt finish it out

Comment: @Stefan I know the boolean is a bit odd that is why I am asking the question

Comment: @Ryan Wilson GetPivotRequest is what I call to generate the object

Comment: @DisplayName: you can shout it, and it's true, but mostly I hear this as an excuse to "never use a pattern" which is awfull. Use of patterns should be encouraged.  It's better to use them, fail and learn then to be afraid of them and not implement them when you should.

Comment: @Stefan no thats not possible

Comment: Another thought, some IoC containers are able to use named registrations; this would give you factory behaviour and IoC/DI in one single kind of abstraction.

Comment: @Stefan we'll just have to disagree. For simple problems use simple strategies. Adding in code that does not benefit readability or maintenance should always be suspect. However, if one needs a factory (mostly for well used/referenced/tested objects) then go ahead.

Comment: _My question is should I be using the Factory pattern at this point or something else_ - it depends on how this object will be consumed. Show the code which uses object you need to create.

Comment: _the exception has nothing to do with this_ - can you remove them, will help to understand code quicker ;)

Comment: @AC25 It looks like you are making lots of `concretepivotrequestfactory` classes, I think the `Bridge` design pattern may help you. It can cut down on you having to make x number of concrete factory classes. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319728/when-do-you-use-the-bridge-pattern-how-is-it-different-from-adapter-pattern/37514779#37514779)